# Stuck on "Unpacking papirus-icon-theme"

Tags: apt, package-management

When I did `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt upgrade`, everything went fine except it got stuck on `Unpacking papirus-icon-theme (20210101-4888+pkg21~ubuntu20.04.1) over (20201201- 4800+pkg21~ubuntu20.04.1) ...` for about 5-10 minutes, so I stopped it and tried it again but it still didn't work.

So then I tried installing an app from terminal but it still wants to update papirus, so I decided to remove it with `sudo apt remove papirus-icon-theme`, but then it said `package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should reinstall it before attempting a removal`, so I tried reinstalling papirus with `sudo apt --reinstall install papirus-icon-theme` but it wanted to unpack it **again**.

How do I fix the unpacking problem or even just remove it completely?

Comment: `apt-cache policy papirus-icon-theme ` and `apt-cache policy` please.

Comment: `apt-cache policy papirus-icon-theme` returns this: https://pastebin.com/c12J9uXU and `apt-cache policy` returns https://pastebin.com/m0KBETcE

Comment: `sudo apt install --reinstall papirus-icon-theme=20200201-1`

Comment: It takes a lot of time, especially on older computers and low end arm devices. But wait for an hour or so, and it should work. **Don't interrupt the installation process**